# Is golang conn.setdeadline for the next operation only or forever?

Tags: go

In the code below:

```
conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Minute)) 
//read/write operation, only once             
conn.SetDeadline(time.Time{})    //cancel deadline
```

Is the "cancel" operation necessary? i.e. If I do not cancel it, the connection **will** timeout in one minute, no matter if following operation succeeds/fails?

Or, the SetDeadline command only applys to the immediate following operation, and after that operation succeeds, the deadline **automatically** vanishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments for the [`Conn` `interface`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn)

> // A deadline is an absolute time after which I/O operations
> // fail instead of blocking. The deadline applies to all future
> // and pending I/O, not just the immediately following call to
> // Read or Write. After a deadline has been exceeded, the
> // connection can be refreshed by setting a deadline in the future.

As stated the deadline applies to "all future" I/O. If you use the connection after the deadline has passed you will get "an error that wraps `os.ErrDeadlineExceeded`". If you wish to use the connection again you will need to set the deadline to a future or zero value (i.e. `conn.SetDeadline(time.Time{})`).

It is important to note that exceeding the deadline does not close the connection. After receiving an `os.ErrDeadlineExceeded` you can still set a new deadline (or clear the deadline) and continue to send/receive. You should not assume that receiving an error means the connection is closed (if that is what you want ensure you call `close()`).